# can't open rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I don't know what I did. I think I updated my Ruby on Rails. After updating it, I always get error when running $rails server.

output is

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

I would restart the console and run rails server and it would work fine for a couple of minutes but then it would stop responding and if I restart rails server it would give me that error again. I tried running on different port (rails s -p 9191) and it gives me the same problem.

Any Ideas what I did wrong? Thnx guys

Answer (score 34):

run it on other port:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

so it'll load on `localhost:3001`

or kill all ruby processes:

```
killall ruby
```

and then run `rails s`

Comment: when I tried rails s -p 3001, it work but then if i restarted it and run it again I would get the error "Already in use - bind(2) Errno::EADDRINUSE)...." I also tried killall ruby but didn't work. It's weird cause I also tried it on my other laptop and it's giving me the same error. Does it have to do with my router or something?

Comment: and yes - it looks like something wrog with your `localhost` environment

Comment: mac OS X (10.6.8). I would start rails server on different port and wouldn't give me errors and restart it right after and it would give me the error.

Comment: so I believe it is network problem. Try to disconnect from your network and run rails in offline

Comment: yea tried doing it offline. still the same error. This is version im running Rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Comment: what does this return: `ps aux | grep ruby` and `ps aux | grep rail`

Comment: ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby script/rails s AND ruby script/rails s -p 3002 AND ruby script/rails s -p 8080 AND ruby script/rails s -p 3001

Comment: and `sudo killall -9 ruby` do nothing?

Comment: yea it doesn't seems to kill the process after doing sudo killall ruby then I did ps aux | grep ruby, it still show scripts/rails -p 3001, script/rails -p 9090 ..... wait sorry forgot to put -9 option yea it killed everything. Tried rails server but still same problem

Comment: `ps aux | grap webrick` or you use mongrel?

Comment: this is what I get from ps aux | webrick "56265   0.0  0.0  2435116    412 s000  R+    1:42PM   0:00.00 grep webrick"  no i don't think I use mongrel

Comment: these are some errors I get from running rails s "/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `new'"  and  ".rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `block in create_listeners'"

Comment: I don't know. Try to update all your gems. Very strange. Looks like `ctrl+c` didn't stop webrick at all, so port is binded by it

Comment: reboot your machine - I get this problem from time to time on ubuntu

Comment: I think my ctrl+c is not stoping rails server properly. Everytime I restart my server I need to manually "killall ruby" to start rails server again.

Comment: oh man this is so stupid of me. I was using ctrl+z all this time to kill my server.  I don't know why suddenly I was using ctrl+z instead of ctrl+x . Stupid of me. Thnx fl00r for your help. I feel so stupid now....

Comment: So that's something, all the other answers I've seen just tell you how to kill the pid and add a new one.

Comment: `killall ruby` was not able to kill the process started in chrome by the Jetbrains IDE support - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji

Answer (score 22):

I think somehow your rails server is keep running after you close it. You can try as

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

see pid and then kill that pid

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Now you can restart your server using

```
rails s
```

**Note:** From next time onwards try using Ctrl D for terminating rails server. That might help

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the issue it all because of ruby instances are not properly terminated.We can terminate processes running in the background by pids.

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

It displays all running pids of ruby.and terminate that pids.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Or use

```
killall ruby
```