# Rails server not starting on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

I have tried

**`rails s -p $PORT -b $IP`**

I am getting no error but getting the help message each time. I also checked if any other server was running but no other process was running. Even then I tried

```
killall ruby
```

but no use.

[Help message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfdfd.jpg)

Comment: did you checked your server error logs?

Comment: What's there in the message you get?

Comment: what's $PORT and $IP ? are you sure they're set ?

Comment: i am getting no error

Comment: @Chauhan find the second answer and try it on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663967/rails-tutorial-chapter-1-rails-server-isnt-working-on-cloud9?rq=1

Comment: the problem is that server is running for other applications.But not running for just one

Comment: @DharmeshRupani that also could't help